# Upgrading to Windows 7 and staying attached to a domain - via VPN

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vpn, upgrade

I want to upgrade my work laptop from XP to Windows 7.

However I work several thousand miles away from the physical network and I connect each day via CheckPoint SecuRemote VPN software.

How can I upgrade my machine whilst remaining attached to the same domain without physically attaching it to the network?

At the beginning of the upgrade process I will no longer have the VPN software installed so I when I set up the computer name and domain my machine will be unable to connect. I imagine I'm going to have to use temporary settings until I get the VPN software but is there an easier way?

Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking the computer off of the domain before you do the upgrade, i.e. add it to a workgroup.  During the upgrade, keep it on the workgroup.

Once the upgrade has completed, simply connect the VPN, and re-add to the domain.

Note - you will probably need to reset the computer account in Active Directory on the server.  Once the VPN has connected, you may also need to temporarily change your DNS server entry on your computer to be your company's internal DNS server, so it can see the Domain Controller to be able to join the domain again through the VPN.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. If I keep the computer name the same, why will the computer account need to be reset?

Comment: There is no easy direct upgrade path from XP to 7 (I should have mentioned that bit).  You have to either upgrade to Vista and then upgrade that to 7 - or use Microsoft's tutorial here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7 which involves the Windows Easy Transfer tool.  The latter method will change the SID of the computer, so Active Directory will see it as foreign.  Not sure if you upgrade XP-Vista-7 - never tried it to be honest!

Comment: Ah, ok so either a straight install or even a format and install are my options. So I'll need to speak with the IT peeps whatever I do.